# How to use star-rating jquery plugin in angular js modal?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use this [star-rating](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating) plugin in my project. I have some criteria on which user have to rate. So I am displaying criteria in modal window. I am using angular bootstrap ui for modal. Not getting how to use this plugin in angular.

My modal's design looks like:

[image: Rating Modal]

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: since you are using angular bootstrap, any reason not to use their star rating?  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/rating

Comment: @MikeOhlsen The only reason, I am not using angular's bootstrap is that it stepping up/down by 1 where I want it to be 0.5.